Group or semi-ring on polytope family
I want to determine how to provide structure to the polytope family; I guess the main article where this is discussed is the one by Peter Mcmullen entitled “The polytope Algebra”, here they talk about the universal group formed by the translation invariant valuation, from where for $\mathcal{F}$ an element of the family of polytopes, a function $\phi :\mathcal{F} \to G$ ($G$ some abelian group) is a valuation if $\phi(P \cup Q) + \phi(P \cap Q)= \phi(P)+ \phi(Q)$ ($P$, $Q$ convex polytopes s.t. $P \cup Q$ is a convex polytope) and a invariant traslation satified $\phi(P + t)=\phi(P)$ I suppose that these functions form an abelian group, but under what operations?.
That's one of the approaches I've seen, because then there's the polyhedron semiring which is defined directly on the polyhedra considering the sum as the convex hull and the product as the Minkowski sum.
But I have not found anything that tells me about operations between polytopes (it could well be the minkowski sum, intersection, union, etc.) and that give a clear structure, any suggestion where to see this? if possible of course, or if this is the only natural way to give structure to polytopes.

Your question is very vague, but you might be interested in "A Category of Polytopes" by Lawrence Vincent Valby, an undergraduate thesis from Reed College (https://people.reed.edu/~davidp/homepage/students/valby.pdf)

But in terms of algebraic structures related/attached to polytopes, in addition to the polytope algebra of McMullen, another such structure that has seen a lot a lot of attention in recent years is the Chow ring of a polyhedral fan, originally introduced by Feichtner and Yuzvinsky (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305142) and later developed by Adiprasito, Huh and Katz (https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02888) who in particular explain how it can be thought of as the space of piecewise polynomial functions on the fan modulo linear functions

Another way to "provide structure to the polytope family" is to look at the deformation cone of a fixed polytope, or to look at the realization space of a fixed combinatorial type of a polytope.
